# htaccess urlrewrite not working on subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I copied the content of my `www folder` in the folder of the subdomain, but now the urlRewrite isn't hooking anymore.

On `www.domain.com` everything works fine, i created `dev.domain.com` to have a working directory but there every url shows the content of the root url (dev.domain.com)

the `.htaccess` of the root folder

```
AddDefaultCharset off
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^org/([^/]*)   /app/organisations/$1    [NC,L]
```

and the `.htaccess` of the app folder

```
AddDefaultCharset off
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/??(.*) /app/index.php/?site=$1&id=$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

Basically the url should be `dev.domain.com/app/site/id?rest`

If i use the url `dev.domain.com/app?site=mySite&id=myId` it works as expected

Comment: And what error do you get for `dev.domain.com/app/site/id?rest` ?

Comment: no error, it just shows the content of the dev.domain.com landingpage

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Comment: yes i get an internal server error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule in `app/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /app/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: yes dev.domain.com/app/site/id?rest is not working but dev.domain.com/app/?site=site&id=id still works :

Comment: This leads to the same result

Comment: To avoid confusion. If i comment out RewriteCond on your .htaccess, i get a 404 not found (?site=mySite&id=myId still works) , if i comment out RewriteCond on my .htaccess i get a 500 Internal Server Error(?site=mySite&id=myId also 500 Error) .

Comment: https://dev.domain.com/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/dev.domain.com/app/index.php?u=/app/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109539/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mazz).